# Aligning Iframe just below the header

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know this is a silly question but I can't seem to fix it.

In my index page, I called the `header.php` and below that I put an `Iframe`

```
<body>


    <?php include 'header.html' ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
        <iframe class="fr" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" marginheight="0" align="top" src="aboutus1.php" frameborder=0 scrolling="no" border="0"  framespacing="0" id="bodyframeid" name="bodyframename" onLoad="autoResize('bodyframeid');" ></iframe>


</body>
```

The problem is, the iframe is aligning with the header at the very top of the page.. I tried padding-top to the iframe, so the iframe moved below the header but when zoomed out it shows whitespace in between.

I'd like to make my page like this:

```
+------------------------------+
|            Header            |
+------------------------------+
|            Iframe            |
|      (contents of Iframe)    |
+------------------------------+
```

**Header.html**

```
<div class="centered">
    <table id="tbheader">
        <tr height="100px">
            <td id="tdlogonavleft"><a href="aboutus1.php" target="contentframename"><img src="images/cti-logo.png" alt="logo" /></a></td>
            <td id="tdlogonavright"><!--img src="images/menu.jpg" /-->
                <div class="menu">
                <ul id="navbar">
                        <li><a href="welcome.php"><img id="active-home" onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-home.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/home.jpg'" src="images/home.jpg" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus1.php" target="bodyframename"><img id="active-aboutus" onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-aboutus.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/aboutus.jpg'" src="images/aboutus.jpg" /></a> 
                            <ul>
                                <li class="x" style="left:-20px;"><a href="aboutus1.php" target="bodyframename">ABOUT CTI</a></li>
                                <li class="x" style="left:-20px;"><a href="aboutus2.php" target="bodyframename">OUR CLIENTS</a></li>
                                <li style="left:-20px;"><a href="aboutus3.php" target="bodyframename">MISSION / VISION </a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="partners.php" target="bodyframename"><img id="active-partners" onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-partners.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/partners.jpg'" src="images/partners.jpg" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="products1_1.php" target="bodyframename"><img id="active-products" onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-products.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/products.jpg'" src="images/products.jpg" /></a> </li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.php" target="bodyframename"><img id="active-contactus" onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-contactus.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/contactus.jpg'" src="images/contactus.jpg" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="bar"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    font-family: verdana; 
    color:#514f4d;
}
html { overflow-y:scroll; }
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
img { border:0; }
.blue { border:1px solid #00b1ef; }
.pageContent {
    width:830px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.container { padding-top:7.5em; }
.bar {
    background: url('images/heading-top.jpg') repeat-x; 
    height:20px;
    z-index:1;
}

.centered {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:830px;
}
.footer {
    background:url('images/heading-bottom.jpg') repeat-x;
    height:20px;
    z-index:5;
width:830px;
}
p.copyright {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:11px;
}
#tbheader {
    border-collapse:collpase;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width:830px;
    border-spacing:0;
top:1em;
}
td#tdlogonavleft {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:190px;
}
td#tdlogonavright {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.menu {
    height:58px;    
    width:425px;
    float:right;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:0;
    margin-right:-1px;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
    background:url('images/menu.jpg') no-repeat;
}
#d_home {
    position:absolute;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url('images/home.jpg') no-repeat;
}
#d_home:hover { 
    position:absolute;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    background:url('images/hover-home.jpg') no-repeat;
}

#d_about {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:85px;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url('images/aboutus.jpg') no-repeat;
}
#d_about:hover {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:85px;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    background:url('images/hover-aboutus.jpg') no-repeat;
}

#d_partners {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:170px;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url('images/partners.jpg') no-repeat;
}
#d_partners:hover {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:170px;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    background:url('images/hover-partners.jpg') no-repeat;
}

#d_products {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:255px;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url('images/products.jpg') no-repeat;
}
#d_products:hover {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:255px;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    background:url('images/hover-products.jpg') no-repeat;
}

#d_contact {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:340px;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url('images/contactus.jpg') no-repeat;
}
#d_contact:hover {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:340px;
    width:85px;
    height:58px;
    background:url('images/hover-contactus.jpg') no-repeat;
}
.x { line-height:1.5em; }
.box {
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    width:270px;
    height:290px;

    -moz-box-shadow 3px 5px 4px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 5px 4px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 4px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);

    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#060606')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#060606');
}
.clear { clear:both; }

/**Navigation**/
#navbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
}
#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#03beff;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
#navbar li ul {
    display: none; 
    width:5.3em;
}

/**
#navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
#navbar li:hover li {
    float: none; }
#navbar li:hover li a {
    background-color: #69f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #000; }
#navbar li li a:hover {
    background-color: #8db3ff; }
```

Comment: What's the code inside of `header.html` look like?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ, I included my codes now :)

Answer (score 1):

Jus simple thing.. 
First of All set this to your iFrame:

```
position:relative;
```

Then Add one more thing for the same:

```
margin-top: 'some int value' px;
```

You can even set -ve values to this.. Try setting a perfect value..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding height to the ".centered" class so it takes up space on the page. Sometimes the contents of a div can be larger than the div itself.